# Can I upgrade my laptop to 8GB of RAM?

Tags: memory, motherboard, 32-bit, acer-aspire

I have an old laptop which I'm trying to upgrade. It's an Acer Aspire 5253 with 32-bit architecture. I am a little confused about how much RAM I can add.

On one side, I've read that 32 bit systems will only support up to 4GB of RAM. But on the other side, if a tipe my motherboard model on Crucial, which is P5wx6, it says that it's compatible with up to 8GB of RAM.

So, what's the catch here? Can I upgrade it to 8GB RAM or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you can upgrade your OS to 64 bit, you can make use of 8GB Ram. Otherwise not.  The limit for 32bit systems is 3.2 GB of Ram. See if your specs (CPU & general) are as on the following review, if yes you can run 64bit for sure: https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-5253-AMD-Fusion-Notebook.49617.0.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The memory is expandable to 8 GB.  Please see this Acer post below:

https://us.answers.acer.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/15801/~/how-do-i-replace-the-ram-memory-on-my-acer-aspire-5253-series-notebook%3F

Your 32-bit OS only uses 3GB  (32-bit limit), so adding memory will not be used or help. You would need to freshly install a 64-bit operating system

Comment: So if I erase windows 7 and install linx mint 64 bit, it would make use of those 8GB RAM?

Comment: You would need to try to see if that works for you

Comment: Do you mean that Linux distro? I've already installed it. And it runs OK with the 2GB RAM.

Comment: I meant you could measure the memory with that system

Comment: What do you mean? That I won't know until I try it... ? Pardon if my questions are stupid xD. I'm very ignorant in the subject.

Comment: Your system can use 8 GB and if you install 8 GB any system will see it and show you

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot :D